# Flask blueprint and registering path

Tags: flask, parameters, blueprint

I am trying to create route and method for it with parameters. Some how I am getting error as "The requested URL was not found on the server."

If I dont pass parameters everything works fine.

app.py has below code :

```
def create_app():

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.secret_key = 'ytestsone'
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(search, url_prefix='/search')
    return app
```

Search.py I have below:

```
search = Blueprint("search", __name__, static_folder='static', template_folder='templates')

#@search.route("/") -->this works
@search.route("/<search_key>") --> this does not work
def search_page(search_key):    --> this does not work
#def search_page(): --> this works 
    print(request.form)
    return render_template("search.html", user=current_user)
```

in my html I have below

```
<div class="col">
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="/search" role="button">Search Item</a>
        </div>
```

can someone please help me what is wrong here with passing parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since you have `url_prefix` in your blueprint, it means the system is looking for all routes that start with that value i.e. `/search`. See this [writeup](https://www.adamsmith.haus/python/examples/1570/flask-construct-a-blueprint-and-set-a-common-url-prefix-for-each-blueprint-route)
2. If your flask route handler is `/<search_key>`, it means Flask is actually expecting a url of type `/search/<search_key>` but the url for your button only has `/search`. Therefore there is no handler for it in your App.
3. You should try this

```
@search.route("/") 
@search.route("/<search_key>") 
def search_page(search_key=None):
```

The above will work for `/search` i.e. @search.route("/") and also work for `/search/abc` i.e. @search.route("/<search_key>"). But you'll have to add code to take care of when search_key is None

Comment: this solved my endpoint issue but it still gives me error when I try to do return render_template("search.html"). 

error: werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'search' with values ['search_key']. Did you mean 'search.static' instead?


my html file has below 
<button onclick="{{ url_for('search',search_key='test') }}"> Search</button>

How should I call url endpoint from html?

Comment: I think the correct thing should be ```url_for('/', search_key='test')``` which should translate to ```/search/test```

Comment: thanks I fixed it using 
<button name="button"  id="btn" onclick="window.location.href='/search/{{search}}'">Search</button>. also added @search.route("/",methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@search.route("/<search_key>" ,methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search_page(search_key=None):